# Can I make eBuddy be the default instant messanger?

Tags: instant-messaging

Was wondering if anyone knows of a way to make eBuddy be the default instant messenger. I'm running on a Galaxy S Captivate. When you click on a contact's icon, it pops up a little toolbar with actions, such as: `Call, View, Text, Email, IM, Navigate`. Clicking on IM launches the built in IM client from AT&T. I'd like it to message the contact using eBuddy instead.

Comment: Good question. BTW your question was the fourth from the top when googling for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you should just be able to do:

Menu->Settings->Applications->Manage Applications
Select the AT&T Messenger App.
Then scroll down in the app Settings and there is a button labelled 'Clear defaults'.
Clicking this will clear any launch by default settings.

Next time you click the text icon on a contact it will ask you what App you want to use.
However maybe AT&T have hacked the phone to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but yeah, the AT&T IM app does not show up in that applications list.

Comment: Bummer. My only suggestion then is to root the phone. Then you can manually remove the AT&T app using the SDK

Comment: @eidylon Have you tried looking in 'All Applications'? It should be there... every app should be there. It might not be called AT&T it might just have the package name e.g. com.att.messenger.

Comment: @mlevit: thanks for the tip. With that I found it by filtering `Manage Applications` to `All` (it defaults to `Third-Party`). When I click on `Instant Messenger` though, the "Clear Defaults" button is disabled and it says `No defaults set.` Ideas where to go from there? I've not quite nerved up to rooting yet... LOL . Feels a bit like flashing a BIOS, which always gave me the willies!  :)

Comment: @eidylon The reason why the 'Clear Defaults' button is disabled is because the defaults have been set in the OS itself therefore they are hardcoded defaults. I would think the only way to change this would be to have an app that can be used from that toolbar... this means that the app has to support that `intent` of send this user a message which I don't believe eBuddy does. My recommendation would be to send eBuddy a request to implement that `intent`.

Comment: Well, at your suggestion I've submitted a request/feedback to the eBuddy site; we'll see what happens...

Comment: @mlevit -- that sounds more like an answer, than just a comment!

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis, agreed! If @mlevit wants to post his comment as an answer, i will `accept` it.